# Vuejs router-link params не передаются данные

Tags: vue.js

Пытаюсь передать данные, которые подтягиваются с помощью геттера через `router-link` в другой компонент

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'cart', params: {cart_data: CART}}">
  <div class="v-catalog__link-to-cart">Cart: {{ CART.length }}</div>
</router-link>
```

и получаю такую ошибку:

[image: props]

, при этом у меня везде в компонентах props `type:Object`, но почему-то приходит строка

Comment: попробуйте в `router.js` этому маршруту добавить `props: true`

Comment: {
    path: '/cart',
    name: 'cart',
    component: () => import('../components/v-cart.vue'),
    props: true
  } тут есть